# No able to capture image via Nokia C Series and send it to Web Server

Tags: java-me

I am making an Application in J2ME, with the use of this application user will be able to capture an image and at the same time upload that image to Web Server, but whenever I use this app in my Nokia C series I am not able to capture an image and whenever use this application via Computer able to capture an image but send command is not working please see the problem and sort out this problem, and guide what I need to do to make this app helpful and useful for me …………….Thanks Amit here

```
public class myMidlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener{
private Display display;
private Form form;
private Command exit, back, capture, camera, send;
private Player player;
private VideoControl videoControl;
private Video video;

int status = 0;
byte localData[];

public myMidlet() {
display = Display.getDisplay(this);
form = new Form("My Form");
    exit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);
    camera = new Command("Camera", Command.SCREEN, 1);
    back = new Command("Back", Command.BACK, 2);
    capture = new Command("Capture", Command.SCREEN, 3);
    send = new Command("Send", Command.OK, 1);
    form.addCommand(camera);
    form.addCommand(exit);
    form.setCommandListener(this);
}

public void startApp() {
    display.setCurrent(form);
}

public void pauseApp() {}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional){
    notifyDestroyed();
}

public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable s){
    String label = c.getLabel();
    if (label.equals("Exit")){
        destroyApp(true);
    } else if (label.equals("Camera")) {
        showCamera();
    } else if (label.equals("Back"))
        display.setCurrent(form);
    else if (label.equals("Capture")) {
        video = new Video(this);
        video.start();

        form.addCommand(send);
        form.removeCommand(camera);
    }
    else if( label.equalsIgnoreCase("Send") ){
        try {
            startSendOperation();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

    }

}
    public boolean uploadImage( String uri, byte[] rawImage)throws Exception
{

HttpConnection httpConnection;
OutputStream    out;

// Open connection to the script
httpConnection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open( uri );

// Setup the request as an HTTP POST and encode with form data
httpConnection.setRequestMethod( HttpConnection.POST );
httpConnection.setRequestProperty( "Content-type", "application/
x-www-form-urlencoded" );

// Encode the imagedata with Base64
String encoded = Base64.encode( rawImage ).toString();

// Build the output and encoded string
String    output    = "imgdata=" + encoded;

// Set the content length header
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString
((output.getBytes().length)));

// Open the output stream and publish data
out = httpConnection.openOutputStream();
out.write( output.getBytes() );

// Flush the buffer (might not be necessary?)
out.flush();

// Here you might want to read a response from the POST to make
// sure everything went OK.

// Close everything down
if( out != null )
if( httpConnection != null )
httpConnection.close();

// All good
return true;
}

public void startSendOperation() throws Exception{

    boolean res = uploadImage( "http://www.xxx.com/postFolder?", localData);

}



public void showCamera(){
    try{
        player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://video");
        player.realize();
        videoControl = (VideoControl)player.getControl("VideoControl");
        Canvas canvas = new VideoCanvas(this, videoControl);
        canvas.addCommand(back);
        canvas.addCommand(capture);
        canvas.setCommandListener(this);
        display.setCurrent(canvas);
        player.start();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {} catch (MediaException me) {}
}

    class Video extends Thread {
    myMidlet midlet;
    public Video(myMidlet midlet) {
        this.midlet = midlet;
    }

    public void run() {
        captureVideo();
    }


    public void captureVideo() {
        try {
            byte[] photo = videoControl.getSnapshot(null);
            localData = photo;
            Image image = Image.createImage(photo, 0, photo.length);

            form.append(image);
            display.setCurrent(form);
            player.close();
            player = null;
            videoControl = null;
        } catch (MediaException me) { }
    }
};
}

class VideoCanvas extends Canvas {
private myMidlet midlet;

public VideoCanvas(myMidlet midlet, VideoControl videoControl) {
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    this.midlet = midlet;

    videoControl.initDisplayMode(VideoControl.USE_DIRECT_VIDEO, this);
    try {
        videoControl.setDisplayLocation(2, 2);
        videoControl.setDisplaySize(width - 4, height - 4);
    } catch (MediaException me) {}
    videoControl.setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    g.setColor(255, 0, 0);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);
    g.drawRect(1, 1, width - 3, height - 3);
}



}
```

Comment: Please someone reply for the same....it's very urgent and also tell me how to check for any nokia device it supports OEM or not????

Comment: i am having the sam eproblem ... can any one having the solution i am having problem in nokia s40 (nokia c1)

Answer (score 0):

In ShowCamera method,Instead of

```
Manager.createPlayer("capture://video");
```

Try using

```
Manager.createPlayer("capture://image");
```